# Why is not TabControl shown with its effect in WPF 2010?

Tags: tabcontrol

Why is not TabControl shown with its effect?
Have you ever seen how TabControl is shown when a window is opened? It is like a papyrus. It works in all my forms, however, it does nit work properly now. 
How to make TabControl work correctly?

```
<TabControl  Height=»420» HorizontalAlignment=”Left” Margin=”0,43,0,0”    Name=”TabControl1” VerticalAlignment=”Top” Width=”553” Grid.ColumnSpan=”2”>
<TabItem Header=”Students” Name=”tabItem1”/>
</TabControl>
```

It is code of a window:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation=”CenterScreen”>
```

How to do it?

Comment: it is available to see effect which I described. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTpaKUm40Nc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Guys, has anybody seen such animation/effect?:)